# MS SQL Server 2005 Backup over a slow (and with a quota) internet link

Tags: sql-server, backup, rsync

I'm using rsync to mirror my samba servers to a offsite linux box via an vDSL Internet link. No worries here. Our daily changes in these files are to small to trigger the daily quota of the link.

Now I'm trying to do the same with MSSQL Backups... i tried rsyncing .bak files. the problem is that if i choose to overwrite the files with a new backup the entire new backup is copied over... the same happens if i use Datebase Publishing wizard to dump .sql files. rsync thinks that the overwrites are entirely new files and copies them as new files (instead of just copy what changed) the problem is that in both cases (SQL Server Management Studio and Database Publishing Wizard) the files gets deleted/rewritten and not overwritten...

is there a simple way to create incrementing backups to a file that rsync recognizes as "things have been added" and not as entirely new files?

thanks for any help!

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could basically make.... attention.... DIFFERNETIAL BACKUPS.

SQL Server supports this. You still create a newfile, but it is basically only the differential since the last full backup.

Besides that - you can use a backup technology that is smarter and only transports file deltas. rsync obviously does not - but i fear this is a little out of your league and normally not available for such scenarios (which are unusual anyway - not saying bad, just unusual).

You baiscally will have to live with the large transfers. THe price for having offsite backups (for which, otoh, I really want to gratulate you).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at:

http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/related.html

http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/appnote/15934.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a 3rd party tool like Red Gate's SQL Backup or Quest's LiteSpeed, which can compress the backup file as it is created. You may get substantial size savings by using one of these types of tools.